# VBA Object variable or With block variable not set error

Tags: excel, vba, exception

I'm having a hard time with VBA errors on Excel, can someone help me understanding what this error means?

*"VBA Object variable or With block variable not set error"*

My function is supposed to check if a sheet exists, if not create the new sheet, rename it and return to the main function.
The code works, but the error is always thrown..

```
Function GetWorksheetFromName(Name As String) As Worksheet
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If StrComp(WS.Name, Name, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set GetWorksheetFromName = WS
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next WS

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        WS.Name = Name
    End With

    Set GetWorksheetFromName = WS

End Function
```

**P.S.:** [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx) might help, but I still haven't fixed my code

Comment: What isn't working? Works for me as `With GetWorksheetFromName("ABC") : .Range("A1") = 123 : End With` . First pass it creates the new worksheet, second pass it uses the same worksheet.

Comment: The code works, but throws-me this error

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: *Which line* throws the error ?

Comment: I just answered the question, I don't really know if I should leave the question or not, but at least the MSDN link can be usefull :/

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WS = .Worksheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
```

note the added period before `Sheets` and `Worksheets` - your current code addresses the Sheets collection of the Active workbook, not ThisWorkbook.

Comment: Still the same... even if I comment the bottom section I still get the error

Comment: I have found the issue, thank you for your time I was actually missing one `Set` statement when receiving the the result of the function... I'm still learning how to process this basic errors with no line numbers :|

Answer (score 0):

The error was actually listed on the [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx)

> **You attempted to use an object variable that has been set to Nothing**.
>
> Set MyObject = Nothing             ' Release the object.
>
> MyCount = MyObject.Count       ' Make a reference to a released object.
>
> Respecify a reference for the object variable. For example, use a new Set statement to set a new reference to the object.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet

Sheets("Config").Select
WS = GetWorksheetFromName(Range("B8").Value)
```

My error was on the last line, I was missing the **SET**

```
Set WS = GetWorksheetFromName(Range("B8").Value)
```

Thank you Tim Williams and Scott Craner for your quick help